# WebDAV mount on macOS readonly

Tags: macos, webdav

Using Finder, I mount a WebDAV share. To do so, I enter the username and password together with servername:port (eg. `http://userName:passWord@local.server:9980/`; ie. `username=userName`, `password=passWord`, `servername=local.server`, `port=9980`).

For some reason, on macOS Sonoma 14.2 the mount is read-only. I cannot create files/folders and cannot delete files.

When I use a different WebDAV client (eg. SolidExplorer on Android) (using same username and password), the mount is read-write.

WebDAV server: I tried multiple. Eg. Docker containers `ugeek/webdav` or `bytemark/webdav` and also nginx directly on "`local.server`".

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with certain WebDAV server implementations, namely nginx. macOS seems to require "Level 2 locking", but nginx doesn't provide that without [some sort of workarounds](https://www.geddy.au/recipes/webdav/nginx-webdav-server).

As I'm not married to nginx in any way, I switched to Apache. The configuration is as simple as this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DavLockDB /srv/dav/var/DavLockDB
    DocumentRoot /srv/dav/data

    <Directory /srv/dav/data>
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

        DAV On
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "WebDAV Data"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpasswd.dav
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/apache2/htpasswd.dav` is the usual `htpasswd` generated auth file; created by running:

```sh
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/htpasswd.dav davuser
```

The `DavLockDB` file `/srv/dav/var/DavLockDB` got created by Apache. Requirement: Directory needs to exist and be writable by the Apache user:

```sh
sudo install -d -m 0775 -o www-data -g www-data /srv/dav/var
```